# How do you pass options to a lua plugin?

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin

In many Neovim plugins these days, configuration is done in a new way, and the readme just says to "pass option_name = someval to enable some behaviour". For example, archibate/nvim-gpt, unfortunately to **dis**able keymappings, described as:

> Can be disabled by no_default_keymaps = true option in setup.

How do I do that? Is it dependent on the plugin manager in use (I'm using vim-plug)? I have tried:

```
require'nvim-gpt'.setup({["no_default_keymaps"] = true})
require'nvim-gpt'.setup({{["no_default_keymaps"] = true}})
require'nvim-gpt'.setup({opts = {no_default_keymaps = true}})
```

I also found some guides which arguably, given the title, should have included this information:

- [Everything you need to know to configure neovim using lua](https://vonheikemen.github.io/devlog/tools/configuring-neovim-using-lua/)
- [Build your modern Neovim config in Lua](https://m4xshen.dev/posts/build-your-modern-neovim-config-in-lua/)

And this one includes one of the attempts I tried above (which doesn't work)

- [Build your first Neovim configuration in lua](https://vonheikemen.github.io/devlog/tools/build-your-first-lua-config-for-neovim/)

Answer (score 4):

```
require'nvim-gpt'.setup {
    no_default_keymaps = true,
}
```

is the correct way. It is not dependent on the plugin manager.

(my mistake was elsewhere, calling this setup function accidentally from two different place in my vimrc, and hence still defining the keymaps.)